# Programmatically changing underline color of EditText

Tags: android

I have an ordinary `EditText` field that I would like to programmatically change the underline color for.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

Other answers suggest changing the background color filter like so:

```java
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

However, I don't see any change when I run the app. Changing the background itself:

```java
editText.setBackground(color)
```

changes the entire `EditText` to `color` - not what I want!

How do I programmatically change the underline color for an `EditText`, `AppCompatEditText` or `TextInputEditText`? I am using version 25.0.1 of the Support Library.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to set the `backgroundTintList` (or `supportBackgroundTintList`) on the `EditText` to an instance of `ColorStateList` containing only the color you wish to change the tint to. An easy way to do this in a backwards-compatible way looks like this:

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);
editText.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
```

This will give the `EditText` the desired underline color.

Comment: FYI, for `setSupportBackgroundTintList` to work (and to use `setBackgroundTintList` in APIs 19+, you'll need to use `AppCompatEditText` instead of `EditText`

Comment: or you can use 
`ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)`
`ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(editText, colorStateList)`

Answer (score 38):

@degs's answer is correct. But just add one little note: the `AppCompatEditText#setSupportBackgroundTintList` is now annotated with `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)` which means:

> [Restrict usage to code within the same group of libraries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RestrictTo.Scope.html#LIBRARY_GROUP)

Instead use [`ViewCompat#setBackgroundTintList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)). So in your example, it should look like this:

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(editText, colorStateList);
```

Comment: It works, but when I click to edittext so it get focus, color is changed to accentColor. How to handle this. My edittext is inside of TextInputLayout if it changes something. Thanks

Comment: @JerabekJakub Attach onFocusChangeListener to your editText and then override it.

Comment: @godslayer_69 Thanks for hint, I have added listener but don't know what to add to method onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {...}. I have tried the same as in answer but without any positive efect. Can you be please more specific?

            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ff6600"));
                ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(editUsername, colorStateList);
            }

Comment: @JerabekJakub inside onFocusChange, from view you can get the id of the view and the boolean b tells if that view is in focus or not, as in true for in focus and false for not. Now using switch case, you can select what should happen for which view, and then just use the above code to apply tint when you want. eg: if view in focus, do something with tint; else do something else with tint.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the color of EditText underline programmatically can be done using ColorFilter class and other ways but you will have an API level problem. The best way to resolve these type of issues is by using a 9-Patch image.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html
go here download a set of drawables and put them in your drawable folder and change the background of EditText programmatically(                `et_joker.setBackground(your_drawable);`
) This will work irrespective to API levels.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it working with the above solution when the edit text is in focus.

I had to add **colorControlActivated** in the theme.

```
<style name="StyledTilEditTextTheme">
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyLight</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/gray_ccc</item>
</style>
```

This worked for me