# TextInputLayout set error without message?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Is is possible to set error on Text Input Layout without showing any error message (i'm already doing it in another place)?.

```
textinputlayout.setError("");
```

won't work unfortunately.

What i basically need is the textInputLayout to change its line color to red, but i need to do it programmatically. Thank you

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838069/programmatically-changing-underline-color-of-edittext]

Comment: thank you but i did already try that, it is meant to work only for edit text without text input layout

Answer (score 11):

You can hide the layout with error like this:

```
textinputlayout.setError("");
if (textinputlayout.getChildCount() == 2) {
    textinputlayout.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: This can get broken at any moment.

Comment: It is really unsafe

Answer (score 9):

Hope it's not too late, but the code behind `setError` is:

```
if (!mErrorEnabled) {
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
      // If error isn't enabled, and the error is empty, just return
      return;
   }
}
```

this means a simple workaround would be:

`textinputlayout.setError(" ");`

please be advised, that this will make TextView with error message visible - so it will make TextInputLayout higher even if it will be empty

since this passes the not-so-well-thought-out case of handling an empty error message request.

Comment: While I don't think that this case isn't well-thought-out, it might simply mean that the TextInputLayout error was meant to take up space and to do that it must be something non-null or non-empty - this answer should get more upvotes since the solution is more manageable.

Comment: textinputlayout.setError(" ");  this is the fastest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The error text (even " ") will take/reserve some height in the TextInputLayout. If you also want to get rid of it then

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout      
    ...
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyZeroSizeTextAppearance"
    ...
    >
```

Text appearance:

```
<style name="MyZeroSizeTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
</style>
```

and then

```
textinputlayout.setError(" ");
```

Comment: If anyone want to do that programmatically 

textInputLayoyt.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.MyZeroSizeTextAppearance);