# Change underline color of edittext if it is filled with input?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Change underline color of edittext if it is filled with input ?

[image]

State :

1. unfocused : color/1
2. focused : color/2
3. unfocused(after input) : color/2

i've try use :

```
edtText.doAfterTextChanged {

}
```

but, i can't find attribut "edtText.backgroundTint" in doAfterTextChanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TextWatcher` for this and `setBackgroundTintList` to change the line color,

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s != null && !(s.toString().isEmpty())) {
                //Color when text exists
                ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(et, colorStateList);
            } else {
                //Default color - color when text does not exist
                ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(et, colorStateList);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43578436/6845131).

Comment: @HaiderSaleem I did. It works fine. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: yeah, it changes whole background not underline.

Comment: that doesn't happen. you can go that using setColorFilter

Comment: yeah, its working if we don't add custom xml background to editText.

Comment: thanks sir, i fill code in afterTextChanged. but, getResource().getColor() deprecate. so, i use ContextCompat.getColor()

Comment: @HaiderSaleem I don't think that's needed in his case.

Answer (score 1):

You can initially use a [selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList) for the `EditText` `backgroundTint` attribute which selects the proper color when it's focused or not

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/focused" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/unfocused" android:state_focused="false" />
</selector>
```

**Your layout**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@drawable/selector" />
```

And when changing the text check if it's empty or not with `TextUtils.isEmpty()`, and change the color accordingly:

```
EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText().toString()))
            editText1.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), R.color.focused));
        else
            editText1.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), R.color.unfocused));
    }
});
```

Repeat the same for all other `EditText` views

Comment: I think having it inside `onTextChanged` would be better. Since that way as soon as the user starts typing, the color would change. but that totally depends on his use case.